# Django form not rendering? (No Model)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

So my Django form is not rendering in the html.

all I'm able to see is the Get Rank text.
I'm not sure if it's because I don't have a model or maybe it's something wrong with my html?

If you need to see anything else let me know not sure what's wrong, I also tried just doing it all inside of the home function but then it doesn't render the html at all.

Side question - Also I only plan on grabbing the users name, and the tag outside their name ("JohnDoeNA#1") so I probably use a get method correct?

EDIT: Fixed the button not working now only thing not rendering is the form. (Mis-spelling)

Updated Code to be correct.

```
views.py: 
from urllib import response
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests
from .forms import SearchUser
import json
# Create your views here.


def index(response):
    return render(response, "main/base.html")


def home(response):
    form = SearchUser()
    data = requests.get(
        'https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/ReallyBlue/NA1?api_key=RGAPI-ee8fcdce-05c5-4ad4-b909-8efa722b1134')
    userid = data.json()['puuid']
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {
        'form': form,
        'userid': userid,
        # 'mmr': apidata['rank']
    })
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms


class SearchUser(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name", max_length=200)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("home/", views.home, name="home")
]
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html'%}


{% block content %}
    <h2>Valorant Ranked Checker</h2>
    <form method="post" action="/home/">
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit", name="search">
            Get rank
        </button>
    </form>
    <p><strong>{{userid}} - {{mmr}}</strong></p>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <title>Blue's Valorant Ranked Checker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content", name="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need a `model` on the `form` for it to show though. Have you tried using `{{ form.name }}`?

Comment: Btw, in the `home` method; `{'userid': userid, 'form': form}` isn't working either?

Comment: as in  return render(response, "main/home.html", {form.name}, {}) ?

Comment: @Damoiskii that above did not work, and correct yes that did not work either, it didn't render the HTML at all whenever doing that so thats what pointed me to know it's something going on with the form itself, or how the html is setup. I am not sure.

Comment: I was referring to your `html` file where you have `{{ form }}`, I'm saying try and use `{{ form.name }}` and see what happens.

Comment: @Damoiskii yes I also gave that a try. Still no luck, tried forms.name, form.name, forms.

Comment: Can you share your related url patterns? Do you want to display the form in the home.html? Which view function renders home.html?

Comment: @Luke correct yes I am wanting to display it there, I will update it now that might just be the issue, I tried adding views.search, and got a function object is not iterable error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main issues here:

1. You were rendering your base template as your root directory (`base.html`) and therefore Django's template inheritance wasn't working correctly. You'll want to render the child template (the one that includes `extends`) if you want template inheritance to work properly.
2. You need to pass your Django form (`SearchUser`) to the `render` function of the view

I recommend making these changes:

====================

Remove reference to the `index` view in your `urls.py` as we don't need it. Instead, use your `home` child template as your root view:

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home")
]
```

====================

Remove the no longer needed `index` function from `views.py`. You'll also want to pass reference to your form (`SearchForm`) inside of Django's `render` shortcut function.

views.py:

```
from urllib import response
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests
from .forms import SearchUser
import json
# Create your views here.

def home(response):
    data = requests.get(
        'https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/ReallyBlue/NA1?api_key=RGAPI-APIKEY')
    userid = data.json()['puuid']
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {
        'form': SearchUser(), # include reference to your form
        'userid': userid,
        # 'mmr': apidata['rank']
    })


def search(response):
    form = SearchUser()
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view function that renders the form and the form template must match. `form` also must be in your context.

Put the form in the `home.html` and change the home view like so:

```
def home(response):
    form = SearchUser()
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {'form': form})
```

Comment: I am loading the form in the /home/ area, if I do this it does the same thing if do it to home function it just displays the html RAW, without rendering anything. I had tried this as well. :/

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you try this please? I tried your code, it works, they just are not in the correct places.

Comment: Correct yes whenever I try this it just displays raw html on the webpage, so it doesn't render anything.

Comment: Fixed it by putting the form : form in the correct place.  It should go with the userid information.

Comment: Yes, `form` was not in your context. That's what I did in the answer.

Comment: @Blue this was what I asked if this `{'userid': userid, 'form': form}` didn't work... by passing the `form` in the `context dictionary`. :-D